# Calling UI Test functions in sequence (Xcode UI Testing)

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I am writing UI Test cases for my app. The problem i am facing is that functions are getting called in an alphabetical order but I want to call the functions in the same sequence I wrote e.g

```
func testLogout(){}
func testWalkthrough(){}
```

Now if you can see the walkthrough screen is the first screen which gets called but because of alphabetical sequence the logout function gets called first which is not the flow of my app

Answer (score 0):

Your tests should not be executed in a specific order. They should keep independent from the order they run.

It is a big deal for test quality when your tests will be executed in a random order.

You can insert your asserts in your test function in the order you need.

Comment: UI Test cases are those cases which actually test the app from the user's perspective how the user is going to interact with the app. I am just confused that if the tests runs in random order if I execute them all at once then some of them will fail because if the user want to go to a home screen he has to pass the signup and login screen 
Can you explain how it will work because am really confused on this

Comment: Each UI test should represent a specific use case / user flow through your app. To achieve that you have to prepare a specific test context, that means a preparation for the test. example: a mocked context with the context you want to test. when you have tests, that have same partials, than you can reuse them (just create some functions for that). Important to know: every test have to be independent from the other test!! That's why the test execution order is independent. In Xcode you have to that an option to run all tests in parallel mode. :)